# Android Studio Zxing Scanner, how to redirect to web page if result from QR code is URL

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing

I'm looking for some help on my android app that are using ZXing scanner. I would like it to redirect to a web site if the result are URL. Thanks in advance.

The following is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;


public class ScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
    }

    public void scan(View view) {
        zXingScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(zXingScannerView);
        zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        zXingScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `handleResult()`:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText()).matches()) {
        // Open URL
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }    
}
```

Comment: any idea why the app are not able to another qr code if i press back button on the web page?